# Is this a possible to achieve using regex?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, centos

Ive got a weird URL giving a 200 status where it shouldn't. It should just give a 404 error. Is there a 404 redirect I can use in htaccess for this?

Good URLs look like this

```
www.example.com/this-is-static/anytext
```

or

```
www.example.com/this-is-static/anytext/alsoanytext_123
```

or

```
www.example.com/this-is-static/anytext/alsoanytext_123-123
```

or

```
www.example.com/this-is-static/anytext/alsoanytext/alsoanytextagain_123-123
```

The bad URL looks like this

```
www.example.com/this-is-static/anytext/alsoanytext
```

**Side note:** The words anytext,alsoanytext and alsoanytextagain are random wildcards * ... they can be any words. The numbers "123" could be any combination of numbers

The " this-is-static " doesn't change

So as you can see, the bad URL doesn't have the part "_XXXXXX"

I basically need it so that if the URL gets up to subfolder "alsoanytext" ( and beyond) **but** no underscore after it, to 404 redirect

Hopefully, this makes sense

**EDIT 2:**

Im not sure below method would work as the regex matches all the URL's except for the "bad one" making this impossible with htaccess without setting up new rules for all the other subfolders.

Just to simplify, using this as an example,( https://regexr.com/5e5fd ) how would we get the line

`www.example.com/this-is-static/anytext/alsoanytext`

to be the only match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to this... the regex and Apache `.htaccess`.

> ```
> www.example.com\/this-is-static\/[^\/\s]*(?:\/[^_\s]+_.*)?$
> ```

@MarcSances appears to have created the regex that matches "good" URLs (+1). (Although do you need `\s` (whitespace) to be part of the negated character class?) Using mod_rewrite you can simply *negate* this regex (with a `!` prefix) to not-match good URLs (ie. successful for "bad" URLs).

In Apache config files you do not need to backslash-escape slashes since the slash carries no special meaning (there are no regex-delimiters, except for *spaces* as argument delimiters). (It's unfortunate that `regexr.com` does not allow you to change the regex delimiters?!)

Note that with the `RewriteRule` directive you only match against the URL-path (less the slash prefix in `.htaccess`), not the hostname.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^this-is-statis\/[^\/\s]*(?:\/[^_\s]+_.*)?$ error.php [R=404,L]
> ```

When you specify a non-3xx status for the `R` flag, the *substitution* string (ie. `error.php` in this example) is ignored. You should specify a single hyphen (`-`) instead to explicitly indicate "no substitution". Also, the `L` flag is superfluous, it is implied.

So, to *negate* this expression it would become:

```
RewriteRule !^this-is-statis/[^/]*(?:/[^_]+_.*)?$ - [R=404]
```

Will serve the 404 `ErrorDocument` for requested URLs that do not match "good URLs".

---

> ```
> /this-is-static/anytext/alsoanytext
> ```

However, it looks like you should be able to match a "bad" URL directly, unless `alsoanytext` itself could legitimately contain underscores (`_`). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^this-is-static/[^/]+/[^/_]+$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response and the last rule did what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following expression with a non-capturing group:

```regex
www.example.com\/this-is-static\/[^\/\s]*(?:\/[^_\s]+_.*)?$
```

Explained:

- Match all the [www.example.com/this-is-static/](http://www.example.com/this-is-static/) regularly.
- Match all but a slash (`[^\/\s]*`).
- `?:` Non-capturing group for the /alsoanytext stuff. The `?` quantifier at the end makes this part optional so /anytext without anything else also matches.
- `\/` Match the slash now.
- `[^_\s]+` Match all but underscore.
- Match underscore `_`.
- Match anything else except line breaks `.*`. Use your preferred method to match the rest of the URL if matching all is not okay.
- Match the end of the string `$`. Required to make sure that nothing follows `/anytext` except the properly formed `/alsoanytext_whatever`. Otherwise, you may have  a partial match when the wrong URL is used (since the beginning will match with `/anytext`).

You can see it at [regexr](https://regexr.com/5e363).

Comment: Thanks for this but I needed to clarify the question,( which I did just now) the "anytext " words symbolize wildcards. Also added one more possible "good URL"

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer to suit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you again but am having trouble telling the rule to take all URLs NOT matching this regex and have them 404, I tried something like RewriteRule ^this-is-statis\/[^\/\s]*(?:\/[^_\s]+_.*)?$ error.php [R=404,L]  but that clearly will do the opposite of what I want

Comment: use a negative lookahead with all my answer then.

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt seem to do it, Ive added a negative lookahead and it doesn't seem capture the last URL ( which is the wrong URL and needs to 404 ) regexr.com/5e589

Comment: Ive added an edit that I think will make this much clearer

Comment: (+1) The other part of this question is implementing this in `.htaccess`, which allows you to easily _negate_ the expression (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64362036/369434)) - to be successful when the regex does not match. I'm curious though why you included `\s` (whitespace) as part of the negated character class?

Comment: Because at regexr I had a plenty of URLs to match and if you don't negate the whitespace/line breaks the character class leaks through the next line. I know it's not required the real situation, but I've included it to match with the regexr answer.

Comment: On the other hand, I acknowledge Nick still needs help with this but I've went through so many attempts to solve his issue with changes on the fly, that I sort of gave up. Glad you cared to complete the answer with htaccess.

Comment: @MarcSances Ah OK, thanks. Maybe a bug with `regexr.com`? Multi-line mode (`m` modifier) should already have prevented that from happening. (?)